# How to bind an object fetched from room database to my view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have this fragment in which I retrieve an object from my database and what I want is to use each field of the object so I can bind them to my view.
In the fragment, I get this string that has the movie's title from my activity. Once I have it, I pass it to the "retrieveMovie" method in my view model that communicates with my DAO file that has the query to retrieve one object:

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT id FROM movie_table WHERE title = title")
    fun retrieveMovie(title:String)
```

This is the part I'm talking about in my fragment:

```kotlin
if (arguments != null){
    val titleString = arguments?.getString("Title")

    //observe viewmodel
    mMoviesViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MoviesViewModel::class.java)
    mMoviesViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        if (titleString != null) {
            mMoviesViewModel.retrieveMovie(titleString)
        }
    })
} else {
    //display error message if arguments are null
    Toast.makeText(context, "Error loading content", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

The thing is, since I get my object through the ViewModel's method, I cannot use it to retrieve its fields (for example, movie.title, movie.poster). So how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you dont need to observe `readAllData`

Then change return of DAO to this

```
@Query("SELECT id FROM movie_table WHERE title = title")
   fun retrieveMovie(title:String) : LiveData<List<Movie>>
```

For binding this to your components use

```
mMoviesViewModel.retrieveMovie(titleString).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {data -> 
    if( data != null ) return@Obeserve
    // Now here you have a object = data : List<Movie> , do your magic here 
})
```

Comment: Thank you but if I do it like  that the 'observe' part there throws the error 'unresolved reference'

Comment: I was able to solve the observe issue but now I still can't access the data's fields

Comment: Its just a list of data (your model) you should be able to access it

Comment: I understand but I'm not able to, its fields just show up as 'unresolved reference'